# What is the best way of Syncing 2 databases?

Tags: java, mysql, database, rest

I am having a desktop application, with a database deployed in the desktop PC. The same database is in the web as well.

I need to sync these 2 databases when requested from the desktop application. Desktop application is developed in `java`, both databases are `MySQL`. Currently I am developing a REST service, so the web application can access it and store data.

But, in choice of `REST` I have to make methods for every database operation and they will be performed one by one. Any better way to sync 2 mysql databases via java?

For more information, the desktop application contain information related to only one user, while the online application contain information of thousands of users. I do not want the desktop application to have any of the other users' information available in the online database.

Comment: I think CouchDB would be a much better fit for what you are trying to achieve. It offer REST API out of the box and replication can be triggered with a simple command (for example ektorp) : `CouchDbInstance dbInstance = ...

ReplicationCommand cmd = new ReplicationCommand.Builder()
                                 .source("example-database")
                                 .target("http://example.org/example-database")
                                 .build();

ReplicationStatus status = dbInstance.replicate(cmd);`

Comment: @MaëlLavault: Thanks, but the question is not related to `CouchDB`

Comment: I know, but you will really have a hard time doing what you want with MySQL. Manually ensuring consistency will be really hard and mysql replication support won't work in your case.

Comment: @MaëlLavault: `mysql replication support won't work in your case.` - why?

Comment: @Tracer One approach is to version the database at the client, when the client connects to the server you can get any outstanding versions of the `roll up` scripts which will bring database versions up-to-date.

Comment: @MaëlLavault MySQL replication has been working for me for years. Your point?

Comment: From what I understood there would need to be multiple master (the different users with their desktop app) and one remote slave aggregating everything. To my knowledge you can't do that with MySQL which support only master/slave (with one master and multiple slaves) or master/master with only 2 databases. I'd be glad to be proven wrong since I need this kind of setup from time to time.

Comment: You're wrong. It supports multi-master and rings.